# Java - XML Deserialization

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap, jackson-databind

I need to make XML soap request like this :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <authenticate xmlns="*Request endpoint*">
        <userName xmlns="">*Personal Information*</userName>
        <password xmlns="">*Personal Information*</password>
    </authenticate>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

and

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <getFullCustomerInfo xmlns="*Request endpoint*">
        <customerNumber xmlns="">*Personal Information*</customerNumber>
        <sessionKey xmlns="">*Session key*</sessionKey>
    </getFullCustomerInfo>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I need to deserialize this to XML string, how can i do this?
I tried to deserialize with Jackson XML Databind library with namespace attributes but it does not work correctly.

I tried to deserialize it with objects like:

Username.class

```
@Setter
public class Username {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "xmlns")
    private String xmlns = "";

    @Setter
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "userName")
    private String username;
}
```

Password.class

```
@Setter
public class Password {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "xmlns")
    private String xmlns = "";

    @Setter
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "password")
    private String password;
}
```

Authenticate.class

```
public class Authenticate {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "xmlns", isAttribute = true)
    private String xmlns = *Request Endpoint*;

    @Setter
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "userName")
    private Username username;

    @Setter
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "password")
    private Password password;
}
```

AuthenticationRequest.class

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Envelope", namespace = "s")
public class AuthenticationRequest {
    @Setter
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Body", namespace = "s")
    private AuthenticationRequestBody gwpAuthenticationRequestBody;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "xmlns", namespace = "s")
    private String xmlns = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
}
```

AuthenticationRequestBody.class

```
public class AuthenticationRequestBody {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "xmlns", namespace = "xsi")
    private String xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "xmlns", namespace = "xsd")
    private String xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

    @Setter
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "authenticate")
    private Authenticate authenticate;
}
```

Eventually, result of deserialization is JsonMappingException: `"Multiple fields representing property "xmlns": *PathRoot*.AuthenticationRequestBody#xsi vs *PathRoot*.AuthenticationRequestBody#xsd"`

When i changed AuthenticationRequestBody.class like this:

```
public class AuthenticationRequestBody {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "xsi", namespace = "xmlns")
    private String xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "xsd", namespace = "xmlns")
    private String xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

    @Setter
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "authenticate")
    private Authenticate authenticate;
}
```

I got result like this :

```
<Envelope
    xmlns="s"
    xmlns:wstxns1="s" wstxns1:
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body
        xmlns:wstxns2="xmlns" wstxns2:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" wstxns2:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <authenticate
            xmlns=""
            xmlns="*Request Endpoint*">
            <userName
                xmlns="">
                <userName>*Personal Information*</userName>
            </userName>
            <password
                xmlns="">
                <password>*Personal Information*</password>
            </password>
        </authenticate>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

When i perform a request i'm getting soap fault:

```
<env:Envelope
    xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <env:Header></env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <env:Fault
            xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
            <faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute &quot;xmlns&quot; bound to namespace &quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/&quot; was already specified for element &quot;authenticate&quot;.</faultstring>
        </env:Fault>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: What do you mean with "but it does not work correctly"? Did you get an error? What is the exact error message? And show us your code, otherwise it's impossible to tell what's wrong with it.